# Adding Docker files and deploy to render web hosting service provider

Tags: laravel, docker

I have my laravel project created with Composer but now want to added Docker files to it, i have installed Docker Desktop.

The issue is when i upload it from git repo to render it successfully deployed but i found this error message when try access the link, ==> No open HTTP ports detected https://render.com/docs/web-services#host-and-port-configuration

My Dockerfile contains:

```bash
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

and I have written this `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  main:
    container_name: Serve
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  queue:
    container_name: Queue
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'php artisan queue:work'
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: Database
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_ROOT: "root"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: PhpMyAdmin
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80

  mailpit:
    image: axllent/mailpit
    container_name: MailPit
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - laravel-exa

networks:
  laravel-exa:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Comment: If you're trying to deploy this to a remote hosting setup, the `volumes:` especially on the `main` container are potentially problematic: they will require you to upload your application source, as well as also providing a built Docker image.  The `php:fpm` base image already contains its own `CMD`, and you don't need a Compose `command:` override.  Does this setup work locally for you?